# 'com.google.android.gms' Confliction when implementing GameAnalytics

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, gameanalytics

I'm Getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
```

When I try to implement GameAnalytics via Fabric.

this is the snipet from the built.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile('com.gameanalytics.sdk:gameanalytics-android:2.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably GameAnalytics also implement this service.

try to add:         exclude group: `com.google.android.gms`

like so:

```
compile('com.gameanalytics.sdk:gameanalytics-android:2.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```